# permissions looping through wrong folder using psexec

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, permissions, psexec

```
for /D /r "C:\Users" %%A in (*Folder*) do icacls "%%~fA" /T /C /grant(:r) "Everyone":(OI)(CI)(F) /inheritance:e >> %log% 2>&1
```

Running this code physically on a machine with a batch works perfectly. The right folders are found and permissions applied and log file displays everything. It does it for the specific folder in each users appdata folder:-

```
processed file: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Folder
```

However if I use PSEXEC to apply the permissions remotely then it goes mental and tries to loop through a application data folder for each user millions of times which no body has access to. Where as stated before it doesn't even try and eventually fails.

```
processed file: C:\Users\Administrator\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\
```

Whats going wrong, thanks.

psexec code:-

```
@echo off

for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%i in ("%~dp0pxhosts.txt") do (
xcopy /y %~dp0permsnet.bat "\\%%i\C$\Temp"
"%~dp0psexec.exe" \\%%i -accepteula -d "\\%%i\C$\Temp\permsnet.bat"
)
pause
```

Comment: Application Data isn't a real folder but a hard link to AppData. AppData has a link to Application Data in it. Usually Application Data normally has permissions of Deny Read Data so programs won't get caught in this loop. Old programs can read/write files to Application Data but cannot dir it.

Comment: Thanks. Might try and do it with out psexec then. Seems odd it's fine at the machine, but not using psexec. If icacls runs over network to hostnames directly I should be able to cobble something together.

Comment: I suspect it's your command that is removing the deny permission on Application Data. Both your `icacls` command and your `For` cmd are recursing through the tree, so lower level folders are having permissions set multiple times. Your command removes most security.

Comment: you answer made me try one more thing before I nearly torched this whole effort, thanks!! Editing OQ...

Answer (score 0):

edit answer found by applying the -s switch the process behaves as normal. @Noodles 
answering with correct info for anyone else with this issue

```
@echo off

for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%i in ("%~dp0pxhosts.txt") do (
xcopy /y %~dp0permsnet.bat "\\%%i\C$\Temp"
"%~dp0psexec.exe" \\%%i -accepteula -d -s "\\%%i\C$\Temp\permsnet.bat"
)
pause
```